# What should I write for my detail view to inhert DB fields for my Django template?

Tags: python, django

I am new in Python. I have a problem with fetching DB fields to my Django template. File detail.html successfully extends my master.html, but it doesn't get anything I wrote under {% block h1 %} {% endblock %}
What should I write under views.py to make it work?

detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}

{% block h1 %}
<div class="box first">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        {% for question  in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="{{ question.slug }}" i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a>
                    <h4>{{ question.naslov }} </h4>
                    <p>{{ question.opis }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>  
  {% endblock %}
  {% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, slug):
    question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

index.html

```
 {% extends "master.html"  %}
 {% block h1 %}
 <div class="box first">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        {% for question  in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="{{ question.slug }} " i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a>
                    <h4>{{ question.naslov }} </h4>
                    <p>{{ question.opis }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</div>  
 {% endblock %}
 {% block title  %} Index {% endblock %}
```

master2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="/static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
        {% include "header.html" %}
        {% include "carausel.html" %}
        {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
        {% include "footer.html" %}
        {% include "nav.html" %}
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

master.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="/static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
        {% include "header.html" %}
        {% include "carausel.html" %}
        {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
        {% include "footer.html" %}
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are rendering latest_question_list to index.html.. The given template is detail.html

Comment: I need the def index for my index.html. Now I should change probably something in the detail.html template

Comment: Yes you should add the above {% block h1%} {% endblock %}in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over `latest_question_list`, but pass `{'question': question}` in the context

Comment: I tried that also. The browser then says 'Question' object is not iterable

Comment: Because it is not, but you try to iterate over it. Chage your your view with `{'latest_question_list':[question]}`  and it will work. Or you can modify your template to not looping over a list of 1 item.

Comment: I tride it. It looks I'm doing something wrong. Can you put me into chat or I could send you my directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% extends "master.html"  %}
```

of index.html to be changed to

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}
```

Comment: I get the same resoult, Difference between master.html and master.html is one include nav,html file

Comment: Did master.html and master2.html has {% block h1 %}{% endblock %} ?

Comment: Yes they are exacty the same, except one include file.

Comment: Please post your master.html